# Every convex polyhedron has only finitely many vertices

Tags: convex-optimization, polyhedra

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, $b \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$. Consider the Polyhedron $\mathcal{P}$ given by

$$
\mathcal{P} = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^{n} \mid Ax \leq b\}. 
$$

Is it true that $\mathcal{P}$ has only finitely many vertices? If not, under which condition it has and is there an upper bound for the numbers of vertices of a convex polyhedron depent on $m$ and $n$?

Comment: Yes, this is true. You can write $\mathcal{P}$ as the intersection of $m$ half-spaces and use induction on $m$ to prove that $\mathcal{P}$ has finitely many vertices (aka extreme points).

Comment: If you view the constraint as $a_k^Tx \le b_k$ then at a vertex you must have at least $n$ constraints active. There are only finitely many solutions to this.

Comment: Can you give a formal proof? And what about an upper bound?

Comment: I should have written "at least $n$ linearly independent constraints active".